# Correct way to bind mat-radio-group to nullable boolean?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a simple form showing data from a REST server.  One of the fields is a boolean but can be null.  My UI has a mat-radio-group with two mat-radio-button elements, one with value "true" and one with value "false".  I would expect that if it was null, neither would be on, and clicking one would set the value to true or false.  However, it doesn't do anything at all.

I tried using ng-value instead of value, but that didn't have any effect.

```
      <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="canBeTrueFalseOrNull">
        <mat-radio-button value="true">yes</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="false">no</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
```

I supposed a can transform the data from the server into strings and then change it back again when I update it, but that seems overly complex.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Here is stackblitz that shows the problem.  I want it to be boolean, not string.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b1gr7p

Comment: Good question. I wonder why so few people are interested in it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To assign a boolean value to each radio button, you should bind the value using the [brackets](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#remember-the-brackets) syntax:

```
[value]="true"
```

Without the brackets, the value is the string `"true"`. The following code snippet should work, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gw1wpy?file=app/radio-ng-model-example.html):

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="canBeTrueFalseOrNull">
  <mat-radio-button [value]="true">yes</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button [value]="false">no</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: Also applied if you are trying to bind value type of Number